# python 3.x overwrite previous terminal line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt, overwrite

I wrote a simple program to calculate average outcome of a dice throw (pretty pointless, but you have to start somewhere ;P):

```
import random, time
from random import randrange

count = 0
total = 0
one_count = 0 

for x in range(10000000):
    random = randrange(1,7)
    count = count + 1
    total = total + random
    average = total / count
    percentage = one_count / count * 100
    if random == 1:
        one_count = one_count + 1
    print("the percentage of ones occurring is", percentage, "and the average outcome is", average)
#   time.sleep(1)
```

To clean it up I want the output to overwrite the previous line. I tried everything I could find, but the only thing I managed to to is to print to the same line without erasing the previous content by changing the last line to:

```
print("the percentage of ones occuring is", percentage, "and the average outcome is", average, "/// ", end="")
```

which outputs:

```
the percentage of ones occuring is 0.0 and the average outcome is 4.0 /// the percentage of ones occuring is 0.0 and the average outcome is 4.5 /// the percentage of ones occuring is 0.0 and the average outcome is 3.6666666666666665 ///
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `\r` at the end. That way, the next line you write will start at the beginning of the previous line. And then flush output so it shows immediately.

Note: If the next line is shorter, the remaining characters will still be there.

Comment: In that case, it's probably something related to your terminal. You should see then [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html)

Comment: I can't import curses: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/jakob/workspace/test/test.py", line 2, in <module> import curses File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module> from _curses import * ImportError: No module named '_curses'`

Comment: You are adding a random `_` at the beginning. Use just `from curses import *`

Comment: nope, the "_curses" gets imported by "curses":

`"""curses

The main package for curses support for Python.  Normally used by importing
the package, and perhaps a particular module inside it.

   import curses
   from curses import textpad
   curses.initscr()
   ...

"""

from _curses import *
import os as _os
import sys as _sys
...`
sorry for the lack of formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

use `end='\r`:

```
for x in range(100000):
    rnd = randrange(1,7) # don't use random
    count += 1
    total = total + rnd
    average = total / count
    percentage = one_count / count * 100
    if rnd == 1:
        one_count += 1
    print("the percentage of ones occurring is {} and the average outcome is {}".format(percentage,average),end='\r')
    time.sleep(.1)
```

On another note using  `total = total + random` is not a good idea, you are importing the random module and using random as a variable name.

Comment: You forgot to change the "random" in line 7 to "rnd", so I just spent 10 minutes troubleshooting why it wouldn't work properly :P

Anyways, I tried adding the end="/r" before, and it still doesn't work, nothing changes... :/

Comment: well you got a good lesson  why not to use module names as variable names ;), it prints all the output on one line for me. are you using the time.sleep also?

Comment: I want to say thanks but the comment box tells me not to do it :)

Comment: I just started using PyDev, my OS is Linux Mint.

Comment: The terminal must be limited like idle.  Can you run it anywhere else?

Comment: Just ran it on my phone, no changes.

Comment: on your phone? do you not have a proper tty to run it from?

Comment: as I said, I ran it from a terminal, I just wanted to see if my phone handles it differently :)